# Finding the correct generic type with Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to build an Adjacency Graph which I have written in JavaScript and convert it to typescript, but I am really struggling with the generic types that I would like to have. Sorry, I am probably in over my head, but seems like it would be super sweet. Here is what I have tried to start with, but cannot figure it out.

```
export type AdjacencyVertex<T> = {
  node: T;
  edges: number[];
};

export class AdjacencyGraph<T> {
  public adjList: Record<number, AdjacencyVertex<T>> = {};
  // public adjList: Partial<AdjacencyVertex<T>>;
  // public adjList: Record<string, any> = {};
  private key: keyof T;

  constructor(key: keyof T) {
    this.adjList = {};
    this.key = key;
  }

  addVertex(v: T): void {
    if (this.key) {
      if (!this.adjList[v[this.key]]) {
        this.adjList[v[this.key]] = {
          node: v,
          edges: [],
        };
      }
    } else {
      if (!this.adjList[v]) {
        this.adjList[v] = {
          node: v,
          edges: [],
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with this I am getting the error:
[image: key of t error]

I guess I am just not really sure how to type this thing. Any help would be appreciated. Also an example usage, for reference would be something like this. these are the tests I wrote for the JavaScript version:

```
  test('should be able to add a vertex as an object', () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph('id');
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    graph.addVertex(node1);
    let node = graph.adjList[node1.id];
    let result = { node: { id: 1 }, edges: [] };
    expect(node).toEqual(result);

    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    graph.addVertex(node2);
    node = graph.adjList[node2.id];
    result = { node: { id: 2 }, edges: [] };
    expect(node).toEqual(result);
  });
```

This is the solution that I finally came up with. Any advice or recommendations are definitely appreciated. All my test are passing also by the way. This is supporting number and complex objects so far:

```
export type AdjacencyVertex<T> = {
  node: T;
  edges: number[];
};

/**
 * AdjacencyGraph<T>
 */
export class AdjacencyGraph<T> {
  public adjList = new Map<number, AdjacencyVertex<T>>();
  private key?: keyof T;

  constructor(key?: keyof T) {
    this.adjList = new Map<number, AdjacencyVertex<T>>();
    this.key = key;
  }

  addVertex(v: T): void {
    if (this.key) {
      if (!this.adjList.get(v[this.key] as number)) {
        this.adjList.set(v[this.key] as number, {
          node: v,
          edges: [],
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (!this.adjList.get(v as number)) {
        this.adjList.set(v as number, {
          node: v,
          edges: [],
        });
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * add Edge
   * @param src{T}
   * @param dest{T}
   * @returns {void}
   */
  addEdge(src: T, dest: T): void {
    if (this.key) {
      if (!this.adjList.get(src[this.key] as number)) {
        this.addVertex(src);
      }
      if (!this.adjList.get(dest[this.key] as number)) {
        this.addVertex(dest);
      }
      if (
        !this.adjList
          .get(src[this.key] as number)
          ?.edges.includes(dest[this.key] as number)
      ) {
        this.adjList
          .get(src[this.key] as number)
          ?.edges.push(dest[this.key] as number);
      }
      if (
        !this.adjList
          .get(dest[this.key] as number)
          ?.edges.includes(src[this.key] as number)
      ) {
        this.adjList
          .get(dest[this.key] as number)
          ?.edges.push(src[this.key] as number);
      }
    } else {
      if (!this.adjList.get(src as number)) {
        this.addVertex(src);
      }
      if (!this.adjList.get(dest as number)) {
        this.addVertex(dest);
      }
      // make sure there are no duplicates
      if (!this.adjList.get(src as number)?.edges.includes(dest as number)) {
        this.adjList.get(src as number)?.edges.push(dest as number);
      }
      if (!this.adjList.get(dest as number)?.edges.includes(src as number)) {
        this.adjList.get(dest as number)?.edges.push(src as number);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param src
   * @param dest
   */
  removeEdge(src: T, dest: T): void {
    if (this.key) {
      let obj = this.adjList.get(src[this.key] as number);
      if (obj) {
        const destKey = dest[this.key] as number;
        obj.edges = obj.edges.filter((v) => v != destKey);
      }
      obj = this.adjList.get(dest[this.key] as number);
      if (obj) {
        const srcKey = src[this.key] as number;
        obj.edges = obj.edges.filter((v) => v != srcKey);
      }
    } else {
      let obj = this.adjList.get(src as number);
      if (obj) {
        obj.edges = obj.edges.filter((v) => v != dest);
      }
      obj = this.adjList.get(dest as number);
      if (obj) {
        obj.edges = obj.edges.filter((v) => v != src);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param v
   */
  removeVertex(v: T) {
    if (this.key) {
      const parent = this.adjList.get(v[this.key] as number);
      const edges = parent?.edges;
      edges?.forEach((edge) => {
        const child = this.adjList.get(edge);
        if (child) {
          if (this.key) {
            const childKey = v[this.key] as number;
            child.edges = child.edges.filter((x) => x != childKey);
          }
        }
      });
      this.adjList.delete(v[this.key] as number);
    } else {
      const parent = this.adjList.get(v as number);
      const edges = parent?.edges;
      edges?.forEach((edge) => {
        const child = this.adjList.get(edge);
        if (child) {
          child.edges = child?.edges.filter((x) => x != v);
        }
      });
      this.adjList.delete(v as number);
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param start
   * @param func
   * @returns
   */
  depthFirstTraversal(start: T, func?: Function): T[] {
    const stack: T[] | number = [];
    if (this.key) {
      // @ts-ignore
      stack.push(this.adjList.get(start[this.key] as number));
    } else {
      // @ts-ignore
      stack.push(start as number);
    }

    const visited = new Map<number, boolean>();
    const result: T[] = [];
    if (this.key) {
      const startKey = start[this.key] as number;
      visited.set(startKey, true);
    } else {
      visited.set(start as number, true);
    }

    while (stack.length) {
      const current = stack.pop();
      if (func) {
        func(current);
      }
      if (current) {
        // @ts-ignore
        result.push(current);
        if (this.key) {
          const neighbors = this.adjList.get(
            // @ts-ignore
            current.node[this.key] as number
          )!.edges;
          neighbors.forEach((neighbor) => {
            if (!visited.get(neighbor)) {
              // @ts-ignore
              stack.push(this.adjList.get(neighbor));
              visited.set(neighbor, true);
            }
          });
        } else {
          if (current) {
            const neighbors = this.adjList.get(current as number)!.edges;
            neighbors.forEach((neighbor) => {
              if (!visited.get(neighbor)) {
                // @ts-ignore
                stack.push(neighbor);
                visited.set(neighbor, true);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  breadthFirstTraversal(start: T, func?: Function) {
    const queue = [];
    const visited = new Map<number, boolean>();
    const result = [];
    if (this.key) {
      const startKey = start[this.key] as number;
      visited.set(startKey, true);
      queue.push(this.adjList.get(startKey));
    } else {
      visited.set(start as number, true);
      queue.push(start);
    }

    while (queue.length) {
      const current = queue.shift();
      if (this.key) {
        // @ts-ignore
        const neighbors = this.adjList.get(
          // @ts-ignore
          current.node[this.key as number] as number
        )!.edges;
        if (func) {
          func(current);
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        result.push(this.adjList.get(current.node[this.key]));
        neighbors.forEach((neighbor) => {
          if (!visited.get(neighbor)) {
            visited.set(neighbor, true);
            queue.push(this.adjList.get(neighbor));
          }
        });
      } else {
        const neighbors = this.adjList.get(current as number)!.edges;
        if (func) {
          func(current);
        }
        result.push(current);
        neighbors.forEach((neighbor) => {
          if (!visited.get(neighbor)) {
            queue.push(neighbor);
            visited.set(neighbor, true);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

All test are passing:

```
import { AdjacencyGraph } from "../src/Structures/AdjacencyGraph";

describe("adjacencygraph tests", () => {
  test("should automatically add the first node", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2]);
    const graph1 = new AdjacencyGraph();
    graph1.addEdge(1, 2);
    expect(graph1.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2]);
  });

  test("should be able to add a vertex as an object", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    graph.addVertex(node1);
    let node = graph.adjList.get(1);
    let result = { node: { id: 1 }, edges: [] };
    expect(node).toEqual(result);

    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    graph.addVertex(node2);
    node = graph.adjList.get(2);
    result = { node: { id: 2 }, edges: [] };
    expect(node).toEqual(result);
  });

  test("should be able to add vertex with a more complex object", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1, name: "mike", job: "developer" };
    graph.addVertex(node1);
    const node = graph.adjList.get(1);
    const result = {
      node: { id: 1, name: "mike", job: "developer" },
      edges: [],
    };
    expect(node).toEqual(result);
  });

  test("should be able to add vertex with simple numbers", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph();
    graph.addVertex(1);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)).toEqual({ node: 1, edges: [] });
    graph.addVertex(2);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(2)).toEqual({ node: 2, edges: [] });
    expect(graph.adjList.size).toEqual(2);
  });

  test("should be able to add edges with just numbers", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph();
    graph.addVertex(1);
    graph.addVertex(2);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addEdge(1, 5);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2, 5]);
  });

  test("should e able to add an edge with objects", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    graph.addVertex(node1);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    expect(graph.adjList.size).toEqual(2);

    let edges = graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges;
    let result = [2];
    expect(edges).toEqual(result);
    const node5 = { id: 5 };
    graph.addEdge(node1, node5);
    edges = graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges;
    result = [2, 5];
    expect(edges).toEqual(result);
    expect(graph.adjList.size).toEqual(3);
  });

  // this is the structure this test is using
  // 1: [2,5]
  // 2: [1,5,3,4]
  // 3: [2,4]
  // 4: [2,5,3]
  // 5: [4,1,2]
  test("should not duplicate edges", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph();
    graph.addVertex(1);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addEdge(1, 5);
    graph.addEdge(2, 1);
    graph.addEdge(2, 3);
    graph.addEdge(2, 3);
    graph.addEdge(2, 4);
    graph.addEdge(3, 2);
    graph.addEdge(3, 4);
    graph.addEdge(4, 2);
    graph.addEdge(4, 5);
    graph.addEdge(4, 3);
    graph.addEdge(5, 4);
    graph.addEdge(5, 1);
    graph.addEdge(5, 2);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2, 5]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(2)!.edges).toEqual([1, 3, 4, 5]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(3)!.edges).toEqual([2, 4]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(4)!.edges).toEqual([2, 3, 5]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(5)!.edges).toEqual([1, 4, 2]);
  });

  test("should not duplicate edges with objects", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    const node3 = { id: 3 };
    const node4 = { id: 4 };
    const node5 = { id: 5 };
    graph.addVertex(node1);

    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node5);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node1);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node5);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node3);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node4);
    graph.addEdge(node3, node2);
    graph.addEdge(node3, node4);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node2);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node5);
    graph.addEdge(node4, node3);
    graph.addEdge(node5, node4);
    graph.addEdge(node5, node1);
    graph.addEdge(node5, node2);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2, 5]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(2)!.edges).toEqual([1, 5, 3, 4]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(3)!.edges).toEqual([2, 4]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(4)!.edges).toEqual([2, 3, 5]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(5)!.edges).toEqual([1, 2, 4]);
  });

  test("should be able to remove an edge", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    graph.addVertex(node1);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    const node5 = { id: 5 };
    graph.addEdge(node1, node5);
    graph.removeEdge(node1, node5);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(5)!.edges).toEqual([]);
  });

  test("should be able to remove an edge with just numbers", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph();
    graph.addVertex(1);
    graph.addVertex(2);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addEdge(1, 5);
    graph.removeEdge(1, 5);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(5)!.edges).toEqual([]);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2]);
  });

  test("should be able to remove a vertex", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    graph.addVertex(node1);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    const node5 = { id: 5 };
    graph.addEdge(node1, node5);
    graph.removeVertex(node5);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2]);
    expect(graph.adjList.size).toEqual(2);
  });

  test("should be able to remove a vertex with just numbers", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph();
    graph.addVertex(1);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addEdge(1, 5);
    graph.removeVertex(5);
    expect(graph.adjList.get(1)!.edges).toEqual([2]);
    expect(graph.adjList.size).toEqual(2);
  });

  test("should return depth first traversal using only numbers", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph();
    graph.addVertex(1);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addEdge(1, 5);
    graph.addEdge(2, 1);
    graph.addEdge(2, 5);
    graph.addEdge(2, 3);
    graph.addEdge(2, 4);
    graph.addEdge(3, 2);
    graph.addEdge(3, 4);
    graph.addEdge(4, 2);
    graph.addEdge(4, 5);
    graph.addEdge(4, 3);
    graph.addEdge(5, 4);
    graph.addEdge(5, 1);
    graph.addEdge(5, 2);
    const result = graph.depthFirstTraversal(1, console.log);
    expect(result).toEqual([1, 5, 4, 3, 2]);
  });

  test("should return depth first traversal using objects", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    const node3 = { id: 3 };
    const node4 = { id: 4 };
    const node5 = { id: 5 };
    graph.addVertex(node1);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node5);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node1);
    const nodeResult1 = { node: { id: 1 }, edges: [2, 5] };
    const nodeResult2 = { node: { id: 5 }, edges: [1] };
    const nodeResult3 = { node: { id: 2 }, edges: [1] };
    const result = graph.depthFirstTraversal(node1, console.log);
    expect(result[0]).toEqual(nodeResult1);
    expect(result[1]).toEqual(nodeResult2);
    expect(result[2]).toEqual(nodeResult3);
  });

  test("should return breadth first traversal using objects", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph("id");
    const node1 = { id: 1 };
    const node2 = { id: 2 };
    const node3 = { id: 3 };
    const node4 = { id: 4 };
    const node5 = { id: 5 };
    graph.addVertex(node1);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node2);
    graph.addEdge(node1, node5);
    graph.addEdge(node2, node1);
    const result = graph.breadthFirstTraversal(node1, console.log);
    const nodeResult1 = { node: { id: 1 }, edges: [2, 5] };
    expect(result[0]).toEqual(nodeResult1);
    const nodeResult2 = { node: { id: 2 }, edges: [1] };
    expect(result[1]).toEqual(nodeResult2);
    const nodeResult3 = { node: { id: 5 }, edges: [1] };
    expect(result[2]).toEqual(nodeResult3);
  });

  test("should return breadth first search on numbers", () => {
    const graph = new AdjacencyGraph();
    graph.addVertex(1);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    const result = graph.breadthFirstTraversal(1, console.log);
    expect(result[0]).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6Levm) is how I might give typings to what you're actually doing, but having `addVertex()` act as some kind of hybrid where maybe the key is not present and therefore `T` is actually a `number` is complex and confusing and hard to achiever type safety; could you just remove that part from your question?  If not, I'd strongly suggest refactoring into two classes to handle the different situations.  Let me know how you want me to proceed with an answer.

Comment: This is the solution that I ended up coming to. It works well and passes all of my tests so far. Any advice is definately much appreciated:

Comment: Wait, did you write up your own answer inside the question? If so you should post it as an answer and not as an edit to the question.  If not then you've changed the scope of the question; do you still want to see my answer to your original question, or should I disengage?